# Matching and splitting a specific line from a .txt file

Tags: perl

I'm looking for concise Perl equivalents (to use within scripts rather than one-liners) to a few things i'd otherwise do in bash/awk:

```
Count=$(awk '/reads/ && ! seen {print $1; seen=1}' < input.txt)
```

Which trawls through a specified .txt file that contains a multitude of lines including some in this format:

```
8523723 reads; of these:
1256265 reads; of these:
2418091 reads; of these:
```

Printing '8523723' and ignoring the remainder of the matchable lines (as I only wish to act on the first matched instance).

Secondly:

```
Count2=$(awk '/paired/ {sum+=$1} END{print sum}' < input.txt)

25 paired; of these:
15 paired; of these:
```

Which would create a running total of the numbers on each matched line, printing 40.

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates on your first point. And second point, count the duplicate lines. May I right.

Comment: Essentially, yes. (1) Take the number from the first line matched, ignore all other lines matched (2) Match all lines and sum the numbers together

Comment: Try  `perl -nE '/reads/ && do {print;exit}' input.txt` and `perl -nE '/paired/ && $sum++; END {say $sum}' input.txt`

Comment: ... and to print only field #1 in the first case: `perl -anE '/reads/ && do {say $F[0];exit}' input.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is:

```
while (<>) {
  if (/reads/) {
    print;
    last;
  }
}
```

The second one is:

```
my $total = 0;
while (<>) {
  if (/(\d+) paired/) {
    $total += $1;
  }
}
say $total;
```

You could, no doubt, golf them both. But these versions are readable :-)